# pyglet.clock.tick is not working

Tags: python, pyglet

I am working with **pyglet** and I find strange what does `pyglet.clock.tick()` return.

`pyglet.clock.tick()` is not working properly, the returned value is different from the elapsed time.

- The update interval is `1/60=0.0625`
- The output values should be: `0.0625`

main.py:

```
import pyglet

window = pyglet.window.Window()

def update(*args):
    pass

@window.event
def on_draw():
    dt = pyglet.clock.tick()
    print(dt)

    # rendering

pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(update, 1.0 / 60.0)
pyglet.app.run()
```

output:

```
0.00023519893125589775
0.00023904764104010212
0.0006876361481085169
0.00020056054319805838
0.00024161344756334913
0.00023306075915385804
0.00038358807515770366
0.00021253430697143472
0.00021167903813035238
0.00019927763993665693
0.00024204108198366825
```

Comment: NameError: name 'wnd' is not defined. Change wnd.event to window.event.  Please test your code yourself before posting it here.

Comment: fixed it wnd = window obviously

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but `pyglet.clock.tick()` returns the last time a `tíck()` was executed, not the delay between scheduled tasks. I'm assuming you want to see how often `update()` was executed, which should be once every `0.0625` seconds right? But that's not what `.tick()` returns, what it returns atm is how fast your code can iterate a render loop, which appears to be every `0.0002` seconds roughly. You can use this to counteract delays in your rendering logic. For instance if a player movement per second got delayed, you can counteract it by messuring tick vs task differentials.

Comment: yes but `on_draw` is called called ~60 times per seconds _(only after the update was executed)_

Comment: I removed `on_draw` and pasted the rendering in the `update`, it works fine, but i still want to know why this code is not working properly.

Comment: I'm not sure where you're getting `0.0625`either. `1/60` is `0.016666`. And according to my tests, `update()` is called every `0.01666` seconds. So this code **is** working. `dt` however still returns how often `tick()` was called (tick checks if it's time to do the scheduled tasks, nothing else) - which happens to be every `0.00035` seconds on my laptop. So your code is working, your expectations are not.

Comment: Try this: https://gist.github.com/Torxed/9f001a5ae912a5649d3f9f7fedada66b - Remember that because consoles take HUGE amounts of time to print stuff, the output will look weird (as if they're executed right after each other)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have used the clock twice per frame.

The `dt` is passed to the `update` function. **Do not** call the `pyglet.clock.tick()` in the update if you use `pyglet.clock.schedule_interval`, it will return the elapsed time since the last `schedule_interval`.

This is how your current time measuring works:

```
0s                     1/60s                   2/60s                   3/60s
|-----------------------|-------|---------------|-------|---------------|
                        <your dt>               <your dt>
```

The code should be:

```
import pyglet

window = pyglet.window.Window()

def update(dt):
    print(dt)

    # rendering

pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(update, 1.0 / 60.0)
pyglet.app.run()
```